# Spivak Chapter 1 Problem 17 Extended.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question in the textbook asks to find a subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ which contains at most one point on every vertical and horizontal line, and whose boundary is $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. The extended question I pose is can we find a subset which contains at most one point on every lines of the form $\frac{y-b}{x-a}=m$ (or $x=a$) where $m\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$?, and whose boundary is $[0,1]\times[0,1]$? I want to find a generalized property when satisfied gives a similar results, for instance  any set of curves which satisfies the condition that for any point $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R^2}$ the set of curves intersecting $(a,b)$ has an open dense complement in $\mathbb{R^2}$.